# Integration between Lambda and SNS topic - Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I was trying to setup EC2 start/stop/reboot email notification using EventBridge-Lambda-SNS. So when Cloudtrail will detect the API RunInstances/StopInstances/RebootInstances, that will match eventbridge rule condition which invokes lambda function to send a customized email body through sns topic.

**Function Code:**

```
import os
import json
import boto3



def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        EventID = event['detail']['eventID']
        Account = event['account']
        Timestamp = event['time']
        Region = event['region']
        InstanceID = event['detail']['requestParameters']['instancesSet']['items'][0]['instanceId']
        EventName = event['detail']['eventName']
        SourceIP = event['detail']['sourceIPAddress']
        InitiatedBy = event['detail']['userIdentity']['arn']
        
        if EventName == 'StopInstances':
            msg_status = 'stopped'
        elif EventName == 'StartInstances':
            msg_status = 'started'
        elif EventName == 'TerminateInstances':
            msg_status = 'terminated'
            
        body = f'Hi Team, \n\nThis is to inform you that EC2 instance with {InstanceID} is {msg_status}.Please find below information. \n\nEventID = {EventID}, \nAccount = {Account}, \nTimestamp = {Timestamp}, \nRegion = {Region}, \nInstanceID = {InstanceID}, \nEventName = {EventName}, \nSourceIP = {SourceIP}, \nInitiatedBy = {InitiatedBy} \n\nRegards,\nCloud Team'
        
        sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
        snsarn = os.environ['snsarn']
        
        res = sns_client.publish(
            TopicArn = snsarn,
            Subject = f'Alert - {InstanceID} is {msg_status}',
            Message = str(body)
            )
```

Then I tested this function by starting/stopping instance and I got expected email body. But apart from this I am getting Lambda invocation output JSON content in email which I don't want.

**Expected:**

```
Hi Team,
    
This is to inform you that EC2 instance with i-0d8219ba97c61c428 is started. Please find below information.
    
EventID = 9b07afa3-222c-4632-9dc9-bfa145ddb573,
Account = 12345678910,
Timestamp = 2023-08-13T04:49:49Z,
Region = us-east-1,
InstanceID = i-0d8219ba97c61c428,
EventName = StartInstances,
SourceIP = <IP>,
InitiatedBy = arn:aws:iam::12345678910:root

Regards,
Cloud Team
```

**Not Expected:**
[image]

Can anyone help me how to stop this activity ? PFA screenshot of email.